# If time is between two hours PHP

Tags: php, date, if-statement, time, between

I looked through all the relevant posts but I can't find where I am going wrong. My goal is to have a picture display if the time is between 6am to 7pm and then have a different one if the time falls between 7pm and 6am.
This is what I have and I am just getting confused now.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Canada/Newfoundland'); // NDT
$current_date = date('G:i:s');

if ($current_date >= 19 && $current_date <= 6) {
     echo "<img src=' $night ' />";
} else {
     echo "<img src=' $day ' />";
}
```

Whenever I run what I have it is ALWAYS the else that shows up so I believe that the issue is with how I am setting up the time?
Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 7):

```
$hour = (int) date('G');

if ($hour >= 6 && $hour <=19) {
    // between 6am and 7pm
} else {
    //between 7pm and 6am
}
```

Comment: Ok. So just having the hour is enough. Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: @FacetiousFemme yes, as it's the only thing you want to compare. In your code you're comparing a full date string against a number

Comment: @MarkEriksson on this same page that I have this, I am now looking to do the same thing but with months/seasons. 
Would I just use $month= (int) date('F'); Or is there another method to get months?
Also I can post another question if it's better then leaving a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your date creation

```
$current_date = date('G:i:s');
```

you're getting a date of the format `19:13:03` so comparing it against the number `19` probably won't work very well.

> - `G - 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros`
> - `i - Minutes with leading zeros`
> - `s - Seconds, with leading zeros`

If you just want the hour, get that

```
$hr = intval(date('G'));

echo "<img src='" . ( $hr >= 19 && $hr <= 6 ? $night : $day ) . "' />";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Timeofday [Time of Day PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettimeofday.php), you are formatting the current time into 24 hour format with minutes and seconds. Since $current_date will always be in xx:xx:xx format, it will never be equal to 6 and 19

Comment: Yes, Ok. Thank you for the link! Always appreciate them!